# php handle put request from backbone.js

Tags: php, backbone.js, put

When backbone.js saves a model to the server, it sends a PUT request. How do I handle these with php? How do I take the contents that are sent with the put request, and store them in a database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another example:

$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

- This would result in an Array (second parameter of json_decode()) $values which would contain your key => value pairs of the received json data.

Answer (score 5):

see the php docs for an example http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

from php.net:

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

you can leave the fwrite part out when you want to store the data to a DB.

Comment: thanks. I'll try it. And when I set up backbone.js to send the data to that php file, it automatically gets sent to the stdin stream?

Comment: yes...but is there a way php://input can  make a distinction between a PUT and POST request.In my case different logic must be implemented for PUT requests and different for POST requests.

Answer (score 4):

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
```

> If you want to work with a legacy web server that doesn't support Backbones's default REST/HTTP approach, you may choose to turn on Backbone.emulateHTTP. Setting this option will fake PUT and DELETE requests with a HTTP POST, and pass them under the _method parameter. Setting this option will also set an X-HTTP-Method-Override header with the true method.

After that implement your own `sync` function in your model: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync